# Do not terminate an application on IIS

Tags: iis

When I put my application on directory and access for first time, the application begins. It's OK, no problem. BUT, after sometime, this application ends end this is normal. Is possible do not terminate by time or extends this time application is running?

Comment: any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to keep the IIS application pool never stop. I suggest you could try to set the start mode to always running.

You could follow below steps to achieve your requirement.

1.Open IIS management console

2.Select the right application pool

3.Click advanced setting

4.Modify the start mode to always running.

[image]

Notice:

When you set the startMode property of your application pool to AlwaysRunning a worker process is spawned as soon as IIS starts up and does not wait for the first user request. But this does not mean the web application is initialized.

When you set preloadEnabled to true, IIS will simulate a user request to the default page (can be changed with initializationPage metabase setting) of the website/virdir so that the application initializes. The request is not logged in the IIS logs.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Right click your IIS web sites

2.Select manage web site

3.Select advanced settings

4.Set the preload enabled to true

[image]

[image]